# Diplay dynamic frontend content in the wordpress backend

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I would like to display frontend wordpress pages under their own menu item in the wordpress backend.

For **static** pages, this works well with the plugin "Admin Menu Editor". However, I am looking for a solution to display **dynamic** content, such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/flow-flow-social-streams/

I tried creating a **custom page-template** (following [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-custom-admin-pages-in-wordpress-1--cms-26829) tutorial) and including the plugin's shortcode using "do_shortcode("[myShortcode]")". However, the site only displays the shortcode's name - no content.

What other ways are there to use a shortcode in the admin backend? I know that using shortcodes in the backend is not good practice, but I do need the functionality in this case.

**EDIT: How I currently integrate the Shortcode**

```
class Submenu_Page {

    public function render() {
        echo do_shortcode( '[ff id="1"]' );
    }
}
```

Comment: post your shortcode here

Comment: edited the post and included the shortcode